# JQuery UI autocomplete "select" event not triggered with single mouse click

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

In my application, I create a table using ajax call. Inside that table, I've textboxes in each row, which are also created dynamically based on the content returned from the ajax call. I need to have autocomplete feature for those textboxes. So far the autocomplete is working fine except on single mouse click. In order to set the textbox value with an item from the autopopulated menu, I need to either **double click** on that item or use **keyboard navigation**. But single click on the item just closes the menu and the textbox value is not changed. Here is the code I'm using.

```
$(".usageTable tr:last").find("#occDpt").autocomplete({
      source:get_depts(),
      select : function( event, ui ){
        console.log(ui.item.value);
        // with single click, this is not printed on the console,
        // but it is with a double click!
        // It's like the select event is not triggered with single mouse click.
      }
});
```

where usageTable is the table thats created on the fly and the textboxes have the id "occDpt".

Please note: I've autocomplete on other static textboxes on the same page, and they work just fine. Not sure why this is not! I'm using jquery version 1.7.2 and jquery-ui version 1.8.14, firefox version 43.0.4.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the issue was with my mouse. I've asked one of collegues to test it on their system. I also tried it on a different computer myself on different browsers. Single click works fine. Finally I replaced my mouse with a newer one. And now it works!